# How do I play Nuka World DLC without Internet?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

I don't have wifi at home so I went to my friend's house to download the Nuka World DLC on Fallout 4 on PS4. I played it at my friend's house for a little bit then went home, and the DLC wasn't there anymore.
How do I play it without Internet?

Answer (score 5):

I assume when you mean *no WiFi*, you really mean *no internet*. From [this website](http://atariage.com/forums/topic/234434-dlc-woes-why-do-i-need-to-be-online/) (I know its for a different game, but its a similar situation), the user found that they needed to be online in order for Playstation to verify that they own a license for the DLC.  Its kind of a DRM protection that Playstation implements.

> Just got off the horn withe customer service. Looks like I'm forced to go online each time to validate the license for the DLC.

[Another forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805627-dragon-ball-xenoverse/71857404) for another different game says the same thing:

> I've been informed that I need to be online to use the content (I'd like to stress that online means the PS4 is connected to PSN, not necessarily that you are online in the game itself)

So since you aren't online, the DLC's license cannot be verified, which is making it not show up.

I found one potential solution for this. On yet [another site](https://community.wbgames.com/t5/Batman-Arkham-Knight-General/Can-you-use-DLC-without-internet/td-p/823266) that discusses this issue (for yet another game), someone mentioned that registering your Playstation will allow you play DLC offline.  They left a [link](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/activation.html) on how to do this.

It looks like the way to do this is the following:

> The first time you sign in to PlayStation™Network, you normally choose to activate your system. To activate your system after you first sign in, select  (Settings) > [PlayStation Network/Account Management] > [Activate as Your Primary PS4] > [Activate].

You can try this, but if it still doesn't work, it looks like you'll need a constant internet connection to play the DLC you purchased.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I just found for the same issue, use phone as mobile hotspot, activate mods/dlc/add on, start game. You can turn off the hotspot after it's going.